# compensating the delay caused by hardware when logging tick data

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if it is too broad.

I dedicated a server for logging data that is being gathered from various sensors (temperature, wind direction ...). In my script, I set to log data (saving into a PostgreSQL database) every second. But when I investigate the data, I notice that sometimes 1 second is missing; for example:

```
2019-10-02 18:23:55,0.32342,67.587
2019-10-02 18:23:57,0.32341,67.582
2019-10-02 18:23:58,0.32340,67.583
2019-10-02 18:23:59,0.32341,67.582
```

Later on I found out that, the delay is not because of delay in reading sensors data but the hardware of the server itself; For example a burst of SSD activity, has caused the delay in execution of script.

Is there any solution or strategy for avoiding or compensating this scenario?

Comment: From a purely statistical point of view, if there aren't too many such missing values, you can just replace them with averages of the two neighbours (unless one of them is also missing - then you'd need to sample more neighbours).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I meant to put this as my last resort; But in stackoverflow, I was wondering maybe there is a way to execute the code in a way that it may not be interrupted by the factors that I described.